# Would Jasmine 2 offer any benefits over Jasmine 1.3 for Protractor?

Tags: protractor

I would like to stay on top of the latest releases. I noticed that Protractor is using Jasmine 1.3 (or is it mini Jasmine).  With newer releases of Jasmine available then is there some additional functionality that these offer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jasmine 2.0 has a couple of big changes, and a lot of internal cleanup.

- it adds asynchronous testing via  done() function, but this is already patched in to the version of 1.3.1 that Protractor uses
- it makes registering reporters easier - this would be nice to have for Protractor
- it changes the syntax for registering custom matchers

We recently tried to update Protractor to 2.0, but it would have resulted in a loss of some functionality. You can see the full discussion at https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/pull/5

Comment: Please note that Jasmine2 is now available for use with Protractor. Simply change the framework to `jasmine2` in your configuration. See http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/jasmine-upgrade for more information.